# How to list files in assets folder react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I created a folder with some subfolders in `android/app/src/main/assets/`. I re-compiled the app and I am trying to get a list of the folder/files I put in there. However, whenever I run one of the following commands (from [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#lspathstringpromise))

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(RNFetchBlob.wrap(RNFetchBlob.fs.asset('subfolder/')))
```

or

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.ls("bundle-assets://")
```

or

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(RNFetchBlob.fs.asset('subfolder/'))
```

I get

> Error: ls error: failed to list path `RNFetchBlob-file://bundle-assets://subfolder/` for it is not exist or it is not a folder at http://localhost:8081/index.android.b...

At least the `assets` folder should exist?
How do I access the files in assets?
Is there a way to do it without `react-native-fetch-blob` by simply passing a `Path`?

Answer (score 2):

`react-native-fs` package has that capability from the looks of it. haven't used it. wish `react-native-fetch-blob` supported it, but nothing in their docs.

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readdirassetsdirpath-string-promisereaddiritem